# Count only datasets that are associated through HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have two models with a HABTM associaton called `LegacyDatum` and `Category` Now I want to count how many Objects of `LegacyDatum` are associated with one or more categories. When I call `LegacyDatum.joins(:categories)` that works but it also returns the datasets with no category. How can I only get the datasets that have at least one category associated?

The Model is really simple, no unconventional associations...
LegacyDatum:

```
class LegacyDatum < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
        .....
        ....
        ...
end
```

Comment: Can u provide your models code?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because `all` is loading everything before the `joins` method is called. What do you get if you drop the `all` portion, or tack it on the end instead?

Comment: srty this was just a stupid typing error^^ corrected it in the post!